# CodeIgniter building a CMS with different page types

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've just started to get into MVC with PHP and have had a good mess about with the likes of CodeIgniter and CakePHP. I'm interested to find out what people's approaches to the following would be:

Normally when I have built a website with a CMS in the past I have approached it by having a core URI table in my database. Each URI is unique and represents a page on my website (e.g. www.example.com/about would reference a record in my URI table with 'about' as the unique URI). The URI table also contains a 'type' column which tells the system what type of page it is (e.g. splash, basic, gallery or whatever). Each 'type' has a corresponding table in my database with all the data for records of that type in them (e.g. I would have tables: basic, gallery and splash). The type also tells the system which template/pagehandler to load which in turn does what it needs to do for each page type.

So if you go to www.example.com/about, my system looks in my URI table for a record with URI 'about', finds it's type to be 'basic' so it loads the basic template/pagehandler which uses the basic table in my database to load and render the page. In the CMS I follow a similar approach, I'll have add/edit forms for all of the different types in my page manager.

I was wondering how you would approach this using an MVC framework such as CodeIgniter? I essentially want to have different controllers for each type of page on both the front and back. However, when someone get's to my site, they will end up on a URI with a single level so I need to check the type of the page and pass off to the correct controller. Is there a way you would recommend of checking the type of each page and then loading the relevant controller to do the rest of the work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My approach eventually was to extend the `_parse_routes()` method of the `Router` class to check the database for any records matching the current uri and set the request with the corresponding value from the database.

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Router extends CI_Router {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function _parse_routes() {
        require_once( BASEPATH .'database/DB'. EXT );
        $db =& DB();

        $routes_table_exists = $db->query("SHOW TABLES LIKE 'routes';");
        if ($routes_table_exists->num_rows > 0) {
            $uri_routes = $db->get_where('routes', array('uri' => $this->uri->uri_string()));

            if ($uri_routes->num_rows > 0) {
                $row = $uri_routes->result()[0];
                if (isset($row->request)) {
                    return $this->_set_request(explode('/', $row->request));
                }
            }
        }

        parent::_parse_routes();
    }

}
```

Whether or not it's the best approach to take it seems to work so far.

Answer (score 0):

Usually its a combination of Routes and naming your controllers. so for example you have an About page, and you don't need a separate About controller. Lets say you have a general Pages controller, and then a view($page) method to retrieve and show the page.

```
example.com/about
$route['about'] = "pages/view/about";
```

if you just have a few pages there are advantages to hard coding the routes - it protects your database. but otherwise taking an example from the tutorial

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
```

this does the same thing but now it will take example.com/*anything can go here*

Versus something like a contact page - where you probably want to have a separate controller called Contact, because you will need to validate the contact form, add it to a database, email it, show a response, show the form again if did not validate, etc So then you can just do a simple link to show the contact form: example.com/contact

the contact form submits to: example.com/contact/submit

more about Routes 
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html

and definitely look at the tutorial it will give you more examples about routes
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/tutorial/index.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That was my initial thought but, what if I want to have a system that is totally managed through a CMS by someone with no code experience. I would like to have different page types which could essentially be anything.. What I'm essentially looking for is a way to pass off control to another controller after establishing the type of page it is. Any ideas?

Comment: I understand what you are saying. and thats why most CMS are so bloated because they want to be everything to everyone. If you want to make a bunch of cool tools for creating a gallery - there is nothing wrong with example.com/gallery which goes to a gallery controller.  My opinion is that a little bit of structure can save you a lot of time. And it keeps it flexible. Adding more controllers is very easy. Also think about the idea that the names of your controllers and models - should make it easier for other developers.

Comment: Yeah that's my reason for wanting to do things myself. I'm aiming to develop my own CMS that is easy to extend or cut down, with a very basic core. While I understand that adding more controllers is easy and makes it flexible - requiring a developer to intervene to add routing rules every time a user wants to add a new page defeats the point of having a CMS. I don't suppose there's a way of pulling routes from a database and using those? That way I could write something to manage the routes within the system.

Comment: they can add a new page without a new controller. look again at the second example -  you can add as many pages as you want automatically. I'm not talking about a new controller per page - i'm talking about if you add new Functionality to your CMS like a search form and paginated results. example.com/search and that goes to a controller named search. Be very wary of burying your basic application logic in a hidden database field.

Comment: Yeah - adding a new page with an already existing controller is fine. The issue comes with the URL. If I want to have a single level URL that doesn't specify the controller name in it such as /basic/view/uri, a route would have to be added. Which would require developer intervention. I want to achieve a system where the full URL is specified by the user, yet it still executes the correct controller based on the page type.

Comment: Basically I'm looking for a way of instantiating a controller from an initially loaded controller. Or customizing how the routing works.

Comment: this looks interesting: http://osvaldas.info/smart-database-driven-routing-in-codeigniter and google the term: dynamic routing codeigniter